# Maven Jar Classifiers

Tags: maven, pom.xml, classification

The pom.xml builds jars with classifiers(for dev, test, stage environments).
E.g.

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>jenkins-dev</id>
        <properties>
            <jar.classifier>default-jenkins-dev</jar.classifier>
        ...............
    </profile>
```

There are 2 branches in mercurial(default, second).

So in the second branch the jar classifier is 'second-jenkins-dev'.

There are several modules(e.g. A, B, C)

The problem occurs when some my modules from default branch were build latest(The latest jar by time of A module is A-default-jenkins-dev.jar) And I try to build the whole war of the 'second' branch. Instead of having the A-second-jenkins-dev.jar as a dependnecy, I get 
A-default-jenkins-dev.jar

Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your strategy to use profile to select the branch to build is confusing and error prone (but that's only personnal opinion).

I think you need to check the following to help you solving your issue:

- do you take care of the profile to checkout the sources that will be build ?
- do take care of the profile to define your dependencies ?
- why the dev profile is activeByDefault ?
- are you using the same jenkins job to build both (default and second) ? In this case take care the workspace will be shared for both build.

Alternative solution:

Modify the pom(s) in branch `second` and don't play with profiles to handle this. Use the artifact `<version>` to handle branches. Keep the `<classifier>` to make distinction between artifact type (for instance you can build a src jar and a class jar based on the same code : that's the idea behind maven classifier)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have understood that it is not a good approach to use classifiers for building artifacts from different branches. I will switch to the <version> as you suggested. Thank you!